# Please explain how to calculate minimum and maximum digits necessary for conversion (ACCORDING to THIS textbook's example)

Tags: math, binary, decimal

I've attached the page of the textbook that explains how to calculate the minimum necessary digits required when converting from decimal to binary. The textbook explanation and implementation of the formula makes no sense to me.

[image]

Is there a typo or something? Or am I misreading it?

---

The explanation states that the maximum value of the destination number system will always be greater than or equal to that of the source destination system. I don't agree with or understand this - can someone please explain it to me. Please.

I agree with and understand that the maximum value of x amount of digits, in a number system with base b, is equal to (b<sup>x</sup> - 1), because it can be proven.

In the decimal system, with 1 digit, the maximum value can be calculated as: (b<sup>x</sup> - 1) => (10<sup>1</sup> - 1) = 9; which is true because the available digits are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and the multiplier is 10<sup>0</sup> (which is 1).

In the binary system, with 1 digit, the maximum value can be calculated as: (b<sup>x</sup> - 1) => (2<sup>1</sup> - 1) = 1; which is true because the available digits are 0,1 and the multiplier is 2<sup>0</sup> (which is 1).

This method proves true for all positional number systems.

But then Forouzan says "Therefore (b<sub>2</sub><sup>x</sup> - 1) ≥ (b<sub>1</sub><sup>k</sup> - 1)", where (b<sub>1</sub><sup>k</sup> - 1) represents the source system and (b<sub>2</sub><sup>x</sup> - 1) represents the destination system. I don't understand this conclusion... because converting from decimal to binary; the binary is the destination system and the decimal is the source system, and we have just proven that with 1 digit the source system (decimal) has a greater value than the destination system (binary):

9 > 1; 1 cannot be greater than 9...

What am I missing here?? How can "(b<sub>2</sub><sup>x</sup> - 1) ≥ (b<sub>1</sub><sup>k</sup> - 1)" always be true?

---

Also in the example they then use the formula as x = ⌈6 * (log 10 / log 2)⌉ but 10 is our decimal base and 2 is our binary base - why are they now suddenly multipliers? Shouldn't it be "log<sub>10</sub> of some other number" and "log<sub>2</sub> of some other number"?

Comment: The decimal system has ten available digits and the binary system has two

Comment: I know... I say that in the question :(

Comment: I think I was reading the piece "In the decimal system, with 1 digit". Maybe I misinterpreted that? Are you suggesting that `2` in base 10 does not need more digits in binary as `10`?

Comment: @cricket_007 But 2 is a value, not a space. 2 in decimal representation has 1 space. 2 in binary representation has 2 spaces.

but the formula doesn't calculate spaces is calculates values => because take 2 in base 10 it would be (10^1 - 1) because the decimal base is 10, the number of spaces required to write two in decimal is 1 and then -1 (I dunno). Which equals to 9, but 2 does NOT need 9 spaces to be written in decimal or binary and two never has the value 9 because it's value is 2. So what is this formula actually for?

Comment: The "number of digits" is the "spaces", or the "characters needed to represent a value in a particular base"

Comment: @cricket_007 Number of digits is 9; number of spaces is 1; value can be anything from 0-9.

Comment: You can say it that way too ;) I think you got your answer

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you understand what I'm asking about the logarithms though?

Comment: You might want to take your logarithm question to http://math.stackexchange.com. Maybe someone there knows how to express the answer better than I can.

Comment: @Welbog I think I got it now, though, sorry it took so long. It would be nice is Wolfram worked in StackExchange, I don't think I bring my thoughts across well. But genuinely and deeply thank you for your time :)

Comment: "Logarithmic properties" are easily searchable.

Comment: @cricket_007 I know the properties, they're in the back of the textbook, that's not the issue - the method just confused the bleep out of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really not phrased well in the source text.

It's saying that if you have a number in base `b1` (such as 10), and a number of digits `k` in that base, (such as 1), then you can represent `b1^k` elements (such as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9), and the largest such element will be `b1^k-1` (i.e., 9).

To find how many digits `x` in some other base `b2`, you need to find an `x` with the property that `b2^x-1 >= b1^k-1`. `b1`, `b2` and `k` are fixed, `x` is an unknown, and you can find it with this formula: `x = ceiling(k * log [base b2] (b1))` (such as `4 = ceiling(1 * log [base 2] (10))`, i.e., you need 4 binary digits to represent the numbers representable with one decimal digit.)

With our example of b1 = 10, b2 = 2, k = 1 and x = 4, we can see that `b1^k-1 = 9` and `b2^x-1 = 15`, and `15 >= 9` is a true statement.

(`log d / log f` is another way of writing `log [base f] (d)`)

Comment: Thank you very much :) - could you also explain why the logs in this case use the bases as multipliers. Because as I understand it x = log(base) * y
                   so in 2^4 => 4 = log(base 2) * y? and in 10^1 => 1 = log(base 10) * y? Because we have bases 10 and 2??

Comment: @einScotchFitch: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why we're using the equation `x = k * log [base b2] (b1)` instead of `x = log [base b2] (b1^k)`? If that is your question then the answer is because of a property of logarithms, which is that `log(a^b) = b * log(a)` for any log base. If that wasn't your question then could you be more specific?

Comment: What I mean is, for an exponential equation the formula is: **b^x=y**, where b is a base (could be 10, could be e, could be 2 or whatever depending on the situation). Therefore for the inverse (or logarithm) the formula is: **log(in base b)y=x** right?

Comment: So, for the decimal equation where (b^k), ignoring the -1, the logarithm would be k = log(in base 10) and then I don't know which variable would be "y" or why we are using 10. And, for the binary equation where (b^x), ignoring the -1 again, the logarithm would be x = log(in base 2) and then; again; I don't know what to substitute for "y" or why it is 2.

What I mean is we treat both log functions as if they are to base 10, but a binary log would be to base 2, because binary is exponentials of 2 not 10. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to teach you logarithms in 600-character comments. The simple definition of a logarithm you have correct: if `b^x = y` then `log [base b] (y) = x`. For your subsequent comments, I believe you are sufficiently confused about logarithms that you should spend some time brushing up on the basics on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: But do you understand what I'm trying to say? In a binary system the base is 2 => 2^0; 2^1; 2^2; 2^3; 2^4... etc. So the base is two. Therefore the logarithm should be => [x = log(base 2) y] **So why are we using log(assumed base 10) 2** in this equation for the binary system? I'm asking why **in this equation** is the binary system using a base 10 instead of a base 2; understand?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, no. Is your concern with the statement `log b1 / log b2`, where we assume that the base of the logarithms are base 10? Like I said in my note above, `log a / log b = log [base b] (a)`, regardless of the base of the first two logarithms. Try this for yourself: `log [base 5] (6) / log [base 5] (200)` and `log [base 14] (6) / log [base 14] (200)`. Both are about `.338175...`, which is `log [base 200] (6)`. The log base doesn't matter for this identity! The textbook assumes you know this and that's part of why it's bad phrasing.

Comment: Yes, my concern is with the statement log b1 / log b2, where we assume that the base of the logarithms are base 10. Because a binary system has base 2 not 10, the same way a hexa system has base 16 not 10 and and octo system has base 8. So why are we assuming base 10 for binary (that is base 2)?

Because you can only multiply and divide logs with the same base, right? Like you can do [log(base10)3/log(base2)5] - can you?

Comment: I'm sorry, if you don't understand my previous comment which answers that very question then I'm not sure how to help you other than to read up on the basics of logarithms and their identities.

Comment: Alright, that's okay, thank you very much for your effort. :)

Comment: This might help you: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/70648.html

Comment: @ Welbog But in all these examples the base is the same. There's no example like in the equation where there is log(b10)y/log(b2)y. In all the examples you give the base is the same for the numerator and denominator. But the bases in our example are different base 10 for decimal and base 2 for binary.

Comment: I'm not talking about [log(base10)10/log(base10)2] - that would make sense; I'm talking about [log(base10)Y/log(base2)Y] because one is decimal and one is binary...

Comment: Numbers don't inherently have bases. Does that make sense? It doesn't matter that you *intend* to treat a number `x` as binary and a number `y` as decimal. `x` and `y` are just numbers. They only have bases when you write them down, or do base-specific math with them. What matters for this case is that the logarithm bases match because that's how this particular identity works. Mixed-base logarithms don't have nice properties and don't make mathematical sense in this context. I'm not sure why you're trying to go down this path.

Comment: The topic right before this one in the book explains how every number system has a unique base. So you can calculate the number of spaces a specific value requires in a specific number system like this: ** number of spaces = log(base of number system)value**   So for example; 234 takes up log(10)234 = 2.37 so 3 spaces in decimal; and log(2)234 = 7.8 so 8 spaces in binary; and log(16)234 = 1.96 so 2 spaces in hexadecimal... And so far every conversion was base specific, so it was strange that this new equation was not. Seeing as it also deals with number systems...

Comment: But I understand now - it's because these numbers aren't actual values in a number system. They are just a counter of the possible values representable by one space. And they just happen to use logarithms as well... they are not related to logarithms in the same way that the number systems are.

Thank you for you patience, really :)

Answer (score 1):

When it says "Therefore (b<sup>x</sup> - 1) ≥ (b<sup>k</sup> - 1)" it means that that the destination space of numbers *must* be at least as large as the source's.  (In order to hold all of them.)

In the second part of your question below the line, I think you may be reading the conclusion wrong.  In the division of the logs, they have the same base.  They are not logs with different bases as you have written.  It is simply `log(b1) / log(b2)`.  That relation follows from the line above.

Refer to [List of log identities #changing the base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base) and [this page about number of digits needed](http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/numdigits.htm).

Comment: Then why use the formula (b^k -1) or (b^x -1) at all? They calculate the maximum value and not the maximum spaces - so why use them in the formula? I'm really sorry that I don't understand :(

Comment: Those are the maximum representable numbers in the destination and source systems respectively.  So they do represent the whole space of each system.

Comment: But base 10 (for the decimal system) to the power of 1 (for example) minus 1 is 9, not 1.

(10^1 - 1) = 9. Not 1?

So the highest value you can get if there is 1 space is 9 - because the highest value digit in decimal is 9 and at space 1 the multiplier is 10^0.
So => (10^1 - 1) = 9, not 1.
but the representation 9 has maximum spaces 1... ?

in decimal number value 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 all only need 1 space, right?

Comment: both (b2^x - 1) and (b1^k - 1) are in base-10 to compare them.  All of `b1`, `b2`, `x`, and `k` are base-10 numbers.  When I said 'space' of numbers, I meant all the possible representable numbers.  So for a one-digit number in base-10, the space of numbers is 9, for a two-digit base-10 number the space is 99.  For a one-digit binary number, the space is 1, and for a two-digit binary number the space is 3.

Comment: How can that be? How can both be to base 10 if one is binary and one is decimal - binary is to base 2, not to base 10.
And how can the space of numbers in 1 digit be 9? There's only space for 1 digit so it can have 9 digits.

**Like if there is 1 space [ ] <- one space** how can you fit 9 numbers into that 1 space? [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9] <- 9 digits take up nine spaces. But the highest value digit to take up one space [ ] <- is "9" because 9 is greater than 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0.

Comment: We are asking what is the minimum number of spaces you need in binary to represent a specific decimal number. So one base is in 2 for binary and one is in 10 for decimal right?

And if so why use this formula? (b^x -1) because it doesn't calculate the number of available or necessary spaces. You don't need 9 binary spaces to represent the decimal number 0 or 1 or 2 or 3, etc.

Comment: Again, maybe it was not exactly the right word, but when I used _space_ of numbers, I meant all the possible representable numbers.  Not the number of [digits in the number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system#Positional_systems_in_detail).  He is using these maximum numbers to produce the relationship (partial inequality) between the relative sizes of the two number spaces.  He is saying for the conversion to work, the destination set of all possible numbers must be as at least large as the source.  The largest possible number for k digits in a base b1 system is the (b1^k - 1).

Comment: Again to be clear, **"number space" = "set of all representable numbers"**.  The point of the book's conclusion is to arrive at a way to determine `x`, the number of digits needed for the conversion from source to destination.

Comment: I know that know :) thank you
I thought it meant literal spaces.